# "И после ей наедине // Давать уроки в тишине!"

Tags: значения, литература

Каково значение слова уроки в следующей строфе Евгения Онегина?

"Как он умел казаться новым,

Шутя невинность изумлять,

Пугать отчаяньем готовым,

Приятной лестью забавлять,

Ловить минуту умиленья,

Невинных лет предубежденья

Умом и страстью побеждать,

Невольной ласки ожидать,

Молить и требовать признанья,

Подслушать сердца первый звук,

Преследовать любовь и вдруг

Добиться тайного свиданья…

И после ей наедине

Давать уроки в тишине!"

Имеются ли в виду уроки "науки страсти нежной" или же Онегин смеётся над любовью девушек, научая их чему-то вместо свидания?

Comment: У М. Веллера есть рассказ "Памятник Дантесу". Если вас действительно очень интересует, что имел в виду поэт (и вы притом не подвержены нервическим расстройствам) - прочтите. (это был комментарий... но я не могу комментировать)

Comment: @ddbug, спасибо, очень занимательно! Слышал, что поэт ругался в стихах и вовсе не был моральным идеалом, но всё равно удивлён. Веллеру можно верить?

Comment: @se0808: the story mentioned above is a work of fiction. Basing research on it is the same as basing research about Caligula on the Tinto Brass's film.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Имеются ли в виду уроки "науки страсти нежной"

Определенно, той самой, "которую воспел Назон", причем во всех смыслах.

> или же Онегин смеётся над любовью девушек, научая их чему-то вместо свидания?

Вы имеете в виду, как это случилось с Татьяной?

```
Но я не создан для блаженства;
Ему чужда душа моя;
Напрасны ваши совершенства:
Их вовсе недостоин я.
и т.д.
```

Нет, в начале первой главе он далеко еще не стал "отступником бурных наслаждений". В начале романа вообще хватает недвусмысленных намеков на опыт веселой столичной жизни: "Вы также маменьки построже за дочерьми смотрите вслед... не то, не то, избави Боже", "Держу я счастливое стремя и ножку чувствую в руках" и пр.

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, что автор намеренно допускает двойственность.

Понятно, что (так как Евгений учился "чему-нибудь и как-нибудь" и обширными научными знаниями похвастать, вероятно, не мог) "науку страсти нежной" герой знал тверже всех остальных наук.

Однако, видя себя в качестве взрослого мужчины, утомленного жизненным опытом, "уроками" можно также считать "чтение морали", "поучения".